# Underscore, find same key and replace value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object like so -

```
{"house" : red, "car" : green, "apple" : blue};
```

and am being sent another object with a single key/value like so

```
{"apple" : green}
```

I need to be able essentially replace the value of "apple" (in this case), with the new value. So I need to find and replace (the value) with the same key as my new item. I have no idea what order the first object will be in each time, so if I can search each time and find and replace the value by matching key that would be great (by index maybe?). Doesn't have to be with underscore , Just have it in to play around with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use underscore.js method [extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)

```
_.extend({"house" : red, "car" : green, "apple" : blue}, {"apple" : green});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regular JS:

```
var myObj = {"house" : red, "car" : green, "apple" : blue};
var newObj = {"apple" : green};

var keyToReplace = Object.keys(newObj)[0] //assuming the new object only has 1 key, else, iterate

if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(keyToReplace)) {
    myObj[keyToReplace] = newObj[keyToReplace]
}
```